# taskkill has no effect when issued under scheduled task while user is logged off

Tags: taskkill

I have a batch file containing the command `taskkill /f /im program.exe` that kills all currently running instances of program.exe.

However, I want to kill program.exe by means of a **scheduled task** while the user initiating the scheduled task is **logged off**.

In this case, the batch file runs at the scheduled time but `taskkill /f /im program.exe` apparently has no effect. Other commands like running a program are not affected, however.

In short: How can I schedule to kill a program when the initiating user is deactivated by 'Switch user' or 'Lock' (i.e. logged off)?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the file extension of your batch file to '.cmd' instead of '.bat' and make sure your file is ANSI encoded instead of UTF-8 (the UTF-8 Byte Order Mark i.e. BOM could make your batch file invalid and throws an unrecognized character at position or line x error). I use Notepad++ for this kind of encoding checks / conversions.

Comment: I have changed this but taskkill commands were still ignored when triggered while logged off

Comment: Hmm. And the user you configured the scheduled task to run under when logged off, is an administrator on that machine?

Comment: Also make sure the 'Run with highest privileges' checkbox is checked on the first tab of the scheduled task. Otherwise UAC will stop you from killing the processes.

Comment: The user is in the group of administrators, and I have checked the 'Run with highest privileges' checkbox, but the task is still not able to kill processes when logged off.

Comment: Maybe there's some parent process that should be killed first. If that also doesn't work, I'm out of options. Sorry I couldn't help.